# iptables returning unknown option "--dport" error

Tags: iptables, kali-linux

I'm attempting to redirect port 80 to 8080 for my MITM ssl strip attack on kali linux rasberry pi, I'm getting the error: `unknown option "--dport"` when trying to run the command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Has anyone else encountered this? or have any idea how I can solve this? I've been scouring the internet for days and can't find anything.

Comment: Someone actually told me the solution. Kali and debian buster use nftables. I needed to switch back to the nftables legacy version and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-m tcp` in between `-p tcp` and `--dport 80`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I discovered that Kali uses `nftables` so whtat I did was to use the `iptables-legacy` mode that nftables provide. So the command would be:

```
iptables-legacy -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

`iptables-legacy` is **not** doing the trick anymore on Debian 11.

Adding `-m tcp` in between `-p tcp` and `--dport 80` solved this for me as suggested in the answer from Joseph. It uses `iptables-extensions` to add the `--dport` parameter for tcp and other protocols, see [here](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#tcp.)

On Debian 11 I had the issue that iptables wasn't able to load any extensions claiming:

```
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): Couldn't load match 'tcp':No such file or directory
```

I was able to solve this by explicitly add `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xtables` to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Kali (and debian buster) actually use nftables - you're going to want to follow https://wiki.debian.org/nftables to switch back to the legacy version that most websites tell you to use.
It's fine if the arptables and ebtables say they don't exist.
nftables is the new way of doing things, if people would ever move to it.